# Dell V105 printer and OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, drivers, osx-snow-leopard, printer

I am trying to get a Dell V105 printer to work with my iMac. It is running 10.6 and I have installed all the drivers on the Snow Leopard disk. I believe there is no official Dell driver but I have also heard the Dell printers are made by third parties that may sell the same printer under different names.

There a quite a few Lexmark models that seem to look very similar and I have tried setting the driver to the 2600 series that looks very similar but that has not enabled me to print. Although it claims to give me the supply levels correctly.

Can anyone help? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

This Dell printer ( and most I believe ) do not support OS X. Dell support says OS requirements for this printer are:

MS Windows XP, MS Windows 2000, MS Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, MS Windows 7, MS Windows Vista

You may want to peruse this site for help:

http://www.openprinting.org/drivers/

You may be able to get some sort of generic driver installed that would at least give you basic printing functionality...

I originally posted a link to the [Gutenprint](http://gutenprint.sourceforge.net/) project, but I think that may be a deadend..

Answer (score 0):

You could run a Windows XP virtual machine on your iMac and then install the print on the virtual machine. I recommend using Virtual Box (http://www.virtualbox.org/).

If you have to do a lot of printing this might not be the most convient solution but if it's just for the odd document it might be worth it.

Comment: The most convenient solution would be a new printer...